# CSS button wont horizontally center

Tags: html, css, web

I can't seem to horizontally center my two buttons.

I have tried adding the following to the landingpage-button element:

```
margin: 0 auto;


margin-left: auto;  
margin-right: auto;
```

I have also tried removing the complete margin part.

**Here is the HTML code**

```
<div class="landingpage-title">WELCOME TO NOVA PLASTOS</div>


<div>
    <a href="#" class="landingpage-button left">Nova Plastos Blog</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="landingpage-button right">Nova Plastos News</a>
</div>
```

**Here is the HTML code, note that I have removed font specific CSS code(e.g. color, family and size) for readability**

```
.landingpage-title {
    width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 180px auto;
}

.landingpage-button {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.landingpage-button:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.landingpage-button.left:link {
    font-family: Georgia;
}


.landingpage-button.right:link {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.landingpage-button:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below option, buttons within div should have text-align:center to center buttons horizontally

```
.btnCenter{
  text-align: center;
}

<div class="btnCenter">
    <a href="#" class="landingpage-button left">Nova Plastos Blog</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="landingpage-button right">Nova Plastos News</a>
</div>
```

Code reference- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OQeLjJ

**Option 2:**

To avoid using another class, use below CSS on landingpage-button class

```
margin: 0 auto;
display:table
```

Code reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/paXJeN

Answer (score 0):

to center with `margin: 0 auto;` you need to declare those "buttons" as `display:block;`

```
.landingpage-button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Remember HTML has actual `<button>` elements, which might be better for your intended purpose

Comment: `display: inline-block` is preferred, since OP likely doesn't want it to be all on its own.

Comment: @jhpratt well, I disagree, since OP was trying to center with margin: 0 auto to begin with, I explained why **that** wasn't working.. but your guess is as good as mine. Nothing in the post would indicate preference for either as far as I can tell.

Comment: Fair enough. OP was probably just seeing various things online, not paying attention to the display type.

Comment: Thanks guys, also learning a lot from the discussion that you are having. I have no preference at the moment (what ever works, works!).